# Field assignement not working as intended in Dart

Tags: flutter, dart, oop, inheritance

```
class FooBase {
  String? name;

  FooBase({required this.name});
}
class Foo  extends FooBase{
  final String name;

  Foo({required this.name}) : super(name: name);
}

void main() {
  final foo = Foo(name: 'foo');
  final fooForm = foo;
  fooForm.name = 'bar';
  print(fooForm.name);
}
```

I would expect this code to print "bar" but it prints "foo". Why so?

How to make it print "bar" ?

Answer (score 2):

You have two `name` fields: one in `FooBase` that implicitly provides a getter and a setter and a `final` one in the derived `Foo` class that provides only an implicit getter.

Therefore when you do `fooForm.name = 'bar';` it invokes the `FooBase.name` setter since that is *not* overridden by the derived `Foo` class.  When you later read `fooForm.name`, you invoke the `name` getter, which *is* overridden by the derived `Foo` class to return the original `'foo'` string.

The morals are:

- [Overriding fields is usually a bad idea](https://github.com/dart-lang/linter/issues/2428#issuecomment-1502013415). (There is [a lint to warn about it](https://dart.dev/tools/linter-rules/overridden_fields).) Override getters and setters instead.
- Trying to make a field non-writable in a derived class is a bad idea anyway.  Doing so breaks the interface and breaks the [Liskov substitutability principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle).

Comment: Thank you for this explanation. I think we can use covariant to override the field `name` like `covariant String name` . I tested, it works. But the drawback is that I wanted to make it `final` and we can't use `final` and `covariant` together

Comment: @TSR Again, you shouldn't be overriding fields.  If you really want, you can provide a `String get name => super.name!` getter and a `covariant` setter.

Answer (score 0):

when you access fooForm.name, it is referring to the name property in the Foo class rather than the name property in the FooBase class.
To make it print "bar", you can remove the name property from the Foo class and directly use the name property from the FooBase class. Here's the modified code:

```
class FooBase {
  String? name;

  FooBase({required this.name});
}

class Foo extends FooBase {
  Foo({required String name}) : super(name: name);
}

void main() {
  final foo = Foo(name: 'foo');
  final fooForm = foo as FooBase;
  fooForm.name = 'bar';
  print(fooForm.name);
}
```